# Hibernate insert query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping, insert-query

During insertion in hibernate query i'm passing some fields as table class objects which i've mapped to corresponding tables, The query works fine but the query is becoming too large because each of these mapped objects are getting updated individually to their corresponding tables.

Can anyone please tell me whether this is the correct way of insertion and also why i'm getting  those update queries.

```
Hibernate: insert into ortms.tool_modified_his_tbl (tool_desc, old_tool_desc, connec1, old_connec1, connec2, old_connec2, landed_cost, old_landed_cost, acqui_date, old_acqui_date, manuf_date, old_manuf_date, price_ref, old_price_ref, op_rate_cost, old_op_rate_cost, stb_rate_cost, old_stb_rate_cost, day_rate1_cost, old_day_rate1_cost, day_rate2_cost, old_day_rate2_cost, packermilling_cost, old_packermilling_cost, sale_value, old_sale_value, status, created_date, modified_date, tool_id, tool_modi_reas_id, tool_modi_usr_id, supplier_id, old_supplier_id, tc_status_id, old_tc_status_id, pricing_type_id, old_pricing_type_id, old_ownership_id, ownership_id, unit_id, old_unit_id, branch_id, old_branch_id, reta_tool_choice_id, old_reta_tool_choice_id, non_ser_tol_cho_id, old_non_ser_tol_cho_id, charge_by_id, old_charge_by_id, size_range_id, old_size_range_id, rack_id, old_rack_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update ortms.master2_tool_master set tool_id=?, tool_desc=?, connec1=?, connec2=?, landed_cost=?, acqui_date=?, manuf_date=?, price_ref=?, op_rate_cost=?, stb_rate_cost=?, day_rate1_cost=?, day_rate2_cost=?, packermilling_cost=?, sale_value=?, uploaded_filename=?, uploaded_file=?, status=?, created_date=?, modified_date=?, supplier_id=?, tc_status_id=?, pricing_type_id=?, unit_id=?, reta_tool_choice_id=?, non_ser_tol_cho_id=?, branch_id=?, charge_by_id=?, size_range_id=?, rack_id=?, ownership_id=? where id=?
Hibernate: update ortms.table_users set user_code=?, username=?, password=?, first_name=?, last_name=?, status=?, created_date=?, modified_date=?, dept_id=?, branch_id=? where id=?
Hibernate: update ortms.table_choice_select set choice_name=?, status=?, created_date=?, modified_date=? where id=?
Hibernate: update ortms.master2_toolmast_chargeby set chargeby=?, status=?, created_date=?, modified_date=? where id=?
Hibernate: update ortms.master2_sizerange set size_code=?, size_range=?, status=?, created_date=?, modified_date=?, grp_lev3_id=? where id=?
Hibernate: update ortms.master2_group_level3 set grp_lev3_name=?, grp_lev3_desc=?, created_date=?, modified_date=?, status=?, grp_lev2_id=? where id=?
Hibernate: update ortms.master2_group_level2 set grp_lev2_name=?, grp_lev2_desc=?, created_date=?, modified_date=?, status=?, grp_lev1_id=? where id=?
After calling action: master2.toolmaster.ToolMaster Time taken: 1234 ms
```

**UPDATION 2**

**ToolModifiedHisTbl.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Mar 2, 2013 9:29:05 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="mappingfiles.ToolModifiedHisTbl" table="tool_modified_his_tbl" catalog="ortms">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>


        <property name="toolDesc" type="string">
            <column name="tool_desc" length="65535" />
        </property>
        <property name="oldToolDesc" type="string">
            <column name="old_tool_desc" length="65535" />
        </property>
        <property name="connec1" type="string">
            <column name="connec1" length="60" />
        </property>
        <property name="oldConnec1" type="string">
            <column name="old_connec1" length="60" />
        </property>
        <property name="connec2" type="string">
            <column name="connec2" length="60" />
        </property>
        <property name="oldConnec2" type="string">
            <column name="old_connec2" length="60" />
        </property>


        <property name="landedCost" type="string">
            <column name="landed_cost" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="oldLandedCost" type="string">
            <column name="old_landed_cost" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="acquiDate" type="date">
            <column name="acqui_date" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="oldAcquiDate" type="date">
            <column name="old_acqui_date" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="manufDate" type="date">
            <column name="manuf_date" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="oldManufDate" type="date">
            <column name="old_manuf_date" length="10" />
        </property>


        <property name="priceRef" type="string">
            <column name="price_ref" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="oldPriceRef" type="string">
            <column name="old_price_ref" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="opRateCost" type="string">
            <column name="op_rate_cost" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="oldOpRateCost" type="string">
            <column name="old_op_rate_cost" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="stbRateCost" type="string">
            <column name="stb_rate_cost" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="oldStbRateCost" type="string">
            <column name="old_stb_rate_cost" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="dayRate1Cost" type="string">
            <column name="day_rate1_cost" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="oldDayRate1Cost" type="string">
            <column name="old_day_rate1_cost" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="dayRate2Cost" type="string">
            <column name="day_rate2_cost" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="oldDayRate2Cost" type="string">
            <column name="old_day_rate2_cost" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="packermillingCost" type="string">
            <column name="packermilling_cost" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="oldPackermillingCost" type="string">
            <column name="old_packermilling_cost" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="saleValue" type="string">
            <column name="sale_value" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="oldSaleValue" type="string">
            <column name="old_sale_value" length="20" />
        </property>

        <property name="status" type="string">
            <column name="status" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="createdDate" type="timestamp">
            <column name="created_date" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="modifiedDate" type="timestamp">
             <column name="modified_date" length="19" />
        </property>






        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.Master2ToolMaster" unique="true" name="toolId" column="tool_id" cascade="all" />
        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.TableModifiedReason" unique="true" name="toolModiReasId" column="tool_modi_reas_id" cascade="all" />

        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.TableUsers" unique="true" name="toolModiUsrId" column="tool_modi_usr_id" cascade="all" />


        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.TableSupplier" unique="true" name="supplierId" column="supplier_id" cascade="all" />
        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.TableSupplier" unique="true" name="oldSupplierId" column="old_supplier_id" cascade="all" />


        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.TableToolContractStatus" unique="true" name="tcStatusId" column="tc_status_id" cascade="all" />
        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.TableToolContractStatus" unique="true" name="oldTcStatusId" column="old_tc_status_id" cascade="all" />


        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.Master2PriceType" unique="true" name="pricingTypeId" column="pricing_type_id" cascade="all" />
        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.Master2PriceType" unique="true" name="oldPricingTypeId" column="old_pricing_type_id" cascade="all" />


        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.TableOwnership" unique="true" name="oldOwnershipId" column="old_ownership_id" cascade="all" />
        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.TableOwnership" unique="true" name="ownershipId" column="ownership_id" cascade="all" />


        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.Master2UnitMaster" unique="true" name="unitId" column="unit_id" cascade="all" />
        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.Master2UnitMaster" unique="true" name="oldUnitId" column="old_unit_id" cascade="all" />


        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.TableBranchesCompany" unique="true" name="branchId" column="branch_id" cascade="all" />
        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.TableBranchesCompany" unique="true" name="oldBranchId" column="old_branch_id" cascade="all" />


        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.TableChoiceSelect" unique="true" name="retaToolChoiceId" column="reta_tool_choice_id" cascade="all" />
        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.TableChoiceSelect" unique="true" name="oldRetaToolChoiceId" column="old_reta_tool_choice_id" cascade="all" />


        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.TableChoiceSelect" unique="true" name="nonSerTolChoId" column="non_ser_tol_cho_id" cascade="all" />
        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.TableChoiceSelect" unique="true" name="oldNonSerTolChoId" column="old_non_ser_tol_cho_id" cascade="all" />


        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.Master2ToolmastChargeby" unique="true" name="chargeById" column="charge_by_id" cascade="all" />
        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.Master2ToolmastChargeby" unique="true" name="oldChargeById" column="old_charge_by_id" cascade="all" />


        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.Master2Sizerange" unique="true" name="sizeRangeId" column="size_range_id" cascade="all" />
        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.Master2Sizerange" unique="true" name="oldSizeRangeId" column="old_size_range_id" cascade="all" />


        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.Master2Racks" unique="true" name="rackId" column="rack_id" cascade="all" />
        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.Master2Racks" unique="true" name="oldRackId" column="old_rack_id" cascade="all" />


    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**TableUsers.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jan 13, 2013 4:26:04 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="mappingfiles.TableUsers" table="table_users" catalog="ortms">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="userCode" type="string">
            <column name="user_code" length="60" />
        </property>
         <property name="username" type="string">
            <column name="username" length="50" />
        </property>
         <property name="password" type="string">
            <column name="password" length="50" />
        </property>
        <property name="firstName" type="string">
            <column name="first_name" length="60" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastName" type="string">
            <column name="last_name" length="60" />
        </property>
        <property name="status" type="string">
            <column name="status" length="20" />
        </property>
        <property name="createdDate" type="timestamp">
            <column name="created_date" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="modifiedDate" type="timestamp">
            <column name="modified_date" length="19" />
        </property>




        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.TableDepartments" unique="true" name="deptId" column="dept_id" cascade="all" />
        <many-to-one class="mappingfiles.TableBranchesCompany" unique="true" name="branchId" column="branch_id" cascade="all" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**UPDATION 3**

i've removed `cascade="all"` attribute from all mappings....now i'm getting one update rest all clear

```
Hibernate: insert into ortms.tool_modified_his_tbl (tool_desc, old_tool_desc, connec1, old_connec1, connec2, old_connec2, landed_cost, old_landed_cost, acqui_date, old_acqui_date, manuf_date, old_manuf_date, price_ref, old_price_ref, op_rate_cost, old_op_rate_cost, stb_rate_cost, old_stb_rate_cost, day_rate1_cost, old_day_rate1_cost, day_rate2_cost, old_day_rate2_cost, packermilling_cost, old_packermilling_cost, sale_value, old_sale_value, status, created_date, modified_date, tool_id, tool_modi_reas_id, tool_modi_usr_id, supplier_id, old_supplier_id, tc_status_id, old_tc_status_id, pricing_type_id, old_pricing_type_id, old_ownership_id, ownership_id, unit_id, old_unit_id, branch_id, old_branch_id, reta_tool_choice_id, old_reta_tool_choice_id, non_ser_tol_cho_id, old_non_ser_tol_cho_id, charge_by_id, old_charge_by_id, size_range_id, old_size_range_id, rack_id, old_rack_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update ortms.master2_tool_master set tool_id=?, tool_desc=?, connec1=?, connec2=?, landed_cost=?, acqui_date=?, manuf_date=?, price_ref=?, op_rate_cost=?, stb_rate_cost=?, day_rate1_cost=?, day_rate2_cost=?, packermilling_cost=?, sale_value=?, uploaded_filename=?, uploaded_file=?, status=?, created_date=?, modified_date=?, supplier_id=?, tc_status_id=?, pricing_type_id=?, unit_id=?, reta_tool_choice_id=?, non_ser_tol_cho_id=?, branch_id=?, charge_by_id=?, size_range_id=?, rack_id=?, ownership_id=? where id=?
```

Comment: What do you mean by "...becoming too large"? Does it give you errors/problems? The whole point of hibernate is to "hide" the RDBMS interaction...

Comment: please post mapping of tool_modified_his_tbl and ortms.table_users, for example

Comment: No Sir...I'm not getting any errors but along with insertion as shown in the output i'm getting several Hibernate updation for the mapped objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unwanted updates come from the "cascade all" settings. You may want to configure it properly according to your needs. For example, have a look here: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/

Comment: sir can you please tell me why now i'm getting only one update along with insert

Comment: it is hard to tell without looking at all the mappings. Did you also take care of the cascades in tool_modified_his_tbl? Please accept my answer if it you think it does good for you. Also, if you need to add something to your question, edit the question itself, do not add an answer. SO is not like a forum. thanks

Comment: Yes sir i've removed cascade="all" from tool_modified_his_tbl....but still the update is coming

Answer (score 1):

Use `dynamic-insert=true` and `dynamic-update=true` at class level

After this your query will be short. It will insert and update only the specified not null values.